# Getting an unexpexted (hash+address) in gnu debuger (gdb)?

Tags: c, assembly, gdb, x86-64, disassembly

I have started in assembly language and using this awesome tool gdb. I have watched many tutorials but I am seeing an unexpected hashtags followed by some address(I have covered them with double asterisk symbols[**]) in gdb while debugging which I cannot understand. Can you please help me with what it is refering to?

```
   0x0000000000001145 <+0>:     push   rbp
   0x0000000000001146 <+1>:     mov    rbp,rsp
   0x0000000000001149 <+4>:     sub    rsp,0x20
   0x000000000000114d <+8>:     mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x14],edi
   0x0000000000001150 <+11>:    mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x20],rsi
   0x0000000000001154 <+15>:    cmp    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x14],0x1
   0x0000000000001158 <+19>:    jg     0x1168 <main+35>
   0x000000000000115a <+21>:    lea    rdi,[rip+0xea7]        **# 0x2008**
   0x0000000000001161 <+28>:    call   0x1030 <puts@plt>
   0x0000000000001166 <+33>:    jmp    0x11a5 <main+96>
   0x0000000000001168 <+35>:    mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rbp-0x20]
   0x000000000000116c <+39>:    add    rax,0x8
   0x0000000000001170 <+43>:    mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rax]
   0x0000000000001173 <+46>:    mov    rsi,rax
   0x0000000000001176 <+49>:    lea    rdi,[rip+0x2ebb]        **# 0x4038 <lisence_check>**
   0x000000000000117d <+56>:    call   0x1040 <strcmp@plt>
   0x0000000000001182 <+61>:    mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],eax
   0x0000000000001185 <+64>:    cmp    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],0x0
   0x0000000000001189 <+68>:    jne    0x1199 <main+84>
   0x000000000000118b <+70>:    lea    rdi,[rip+0xea3]        **# 0x2035**
   0x0000000000001192 <+77>:    call   0x1030 <puts@plt>
   0x0000000000001197 <+82>:    jmp    0x11a5 <main+96>
   0x0000000000001199 <+84>:    lea    rdi,[rip+0xea5]        **# 0x2045**
--Type <RET> for more, q to quit, c to continue without paging--c
   0x00000000000011a0 <+91>:    call   0x1030 <puts@plt>
   0x00000000000011a5 <+96>:    mov    eax,0x0
   0x00000000000011aa <+101>:   leave  
   0x00000000000011ab <+102>:   ret
```

Comment: It's decoding the RIP-relative addressing for you.  Of course, the program hasn't started yet so those aren't yet the absolute addresses the code will actually use, because it's still looking at the code as starting at `0x1000`.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks for such immediate answer. I got rest of it but can you please explain why it is showing <lisence_check>(at 0x0000000000001176), because as far I can understand it is refering to a function but there is not such funtion named <lisence_check> in the file.

Comment: That's very unlikely to be a function; notice that it's passing the symbol address as the first arg to `strcmp`, I think comparing it against `argv[1]`.  It wouldn't make sense to do that with bytes of machine code.  Use GDB's `x` command to examine memory at `lisence_check`.  Weird to have a spelling error in the symbol name, BTW. ("License" is the English word that would make sense there)